# google maps iOS SDK: custom icons to be used as markers

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-sdk-ios

The Android API has a very convenient class for this, [`IconGenerator`](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/ui/IconGenerator.html). Using the `IconGenerator` **in my Android app**, I can easily make a marker that:

1. is a simple rectangle with the color of my choosing.
2. resizes to hold text of any length.
3. is **NOT** an info window - I'd like the marker itself to contain the text as shown in the image below from the android version.

[image]

```java
// Android - problem solved with IconGenerator
IconGenerator iconGenerator = new IconGenerator(context);
iconGenerator.setStyle(IconGenerator.STYLE_GREEN); // or any other color
Bitmap iconBitmap = iconGenerator.makeIcon(myString);
Marker m = new MarkerOptions().icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(iconBitmap))
                              .position(myLatLng);
map.addMarker(m); // map is a com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap
```

Is there a way to do something as simple as this in **iOS using Swift**?
There has been a [recent release](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-ios-utils/releases/tag/v1.1.0) of the iOS api that allows "marker customization", but I don't see how to apply it to this use case.

```swift
// iOS (Swift) - I don't know how to create the icon as in code above
let marker = GMSMarker(position: myLatLng)
marker.icon = // How can I set to a rectangle with color/text of my choosing?
marker.map = map // map is a GMSMapView
```

Comment: Thats what I have mentioned, create a `UIView` same as your android which consits of your $ price and then create a `UIImage` from it, which I have mentioned the same function for.

Comment: I edited my question before I saw your updated answer. I'll implement this tomorrow. In the meantime can you please be a little more specific on what the UIVIew/label code would look like.

Comment: Ok, I ll try to make a similar view what you want. It is just nothing but a view which will be converted to the image. You can use BezierPaths to achieve the down arrow point shape like view. Also if you don't want what I did on top of marker, simply delete `mapView.selectedMarker = marker` line and it will be a simple marker

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Here is what I have done

```
let marker = GMSMarker()

// I have taken a pin image which is a custom image
let markerImage = UIImage(named: "mapMarker")!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)

//creating a marker view
let markerView = UIImageView(image: markerImage)

//changing the tint color of the image
markerView.tintColor = UIColor.red

marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 28.7041, longitude: 77.1025)

marker.iconView = markerView
marker.title = "New Delhi"
marker.snippet = "India"
marker.map = mapView

//comment this line if you don't wish to put a callout bubble
mapView.selectedMarker = marker
```

The output is

[image]

And my marker image was

[image]

You can change your color as per your need. Also if you want something in rectange, you can just create a simple small rectangular image and use it like I did above and change the color of your need.

Or if you want a rectangle with text within it, you can just create a small `UIView` with some label and then convert that `UIView` in `UIImage` and can do the same thing.

```
//function to convert the given UIView into a UIImage
func imageWithView(view:UIView) -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, false, 0.0)
    view.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image!
}
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: I've tried to use `imageWithView` with [this constraint code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40567858/1168364): `let label = UILabel()` and `label.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(50.0).active = true` but I get crash due to `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` inside `imageWithView` being nil.

Comment: How to setting center title and snippet ?

Answer (score 6):

Here is what i have done for solving the same issue, that you are facing.

I have added below image in my image assets,

[image]

Now i added below method in my code:

```
-(UIImage*)drawText:(NSString*)text inImage:(UIImage*)image
{
    UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:11];
    CGSize size = image.size;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0.0f);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);

    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
    paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    NSDictionary *attributes = @{
                                 NSFontAttributeName : font,
                                 NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : paragraphStyle,
                                 NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor redColor]
                                 };
    CGSize textSize = [text sizeWithAttributes:attributes];
    CGRect textRect = CGRectMake((rect.size.width-textSize.width)/2, (rect.size.height-textSize.height)/2 - 2, textSize.width, textSize.height);
    [text drawInRect:CGRectIntegral(textRect) withAttributes:attributes];

    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

Now, I called this method, while assigning icon to GMSMarker, like this:

```
marker.icon = [self drawText:@"$33.6" inImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-marker"]];
```

It will generate the image icon like below:

[image]

Here, I kept the background Image size fixed, as i needed. You can still customize it to adjust it according to text size, as well as multiple lines.

**UPDATE**

Updated code in Swift:

```
func drawText(text:NSString, inImage:UIImage) -> UIImage? {

        let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 11)
        let size = inImage.size

        //UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
        let scale = UIScreen.main.scale
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(inImage.size, false, scale)
        inImage.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height))
        let style : NSMutableParagraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle.default.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableParagraphStyle
        style.alignment = .center
        let attributes:NSDictionary = [ NSAttributedString.Key.font : font, NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle : style, NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.black ]

        let textSize = text.size(withAttributes: attributes as? [NSAttributedString.Key : Any])
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: inImage.size.width, height: inImage.size.height)
        let textRect = CGRect(x: (rect.size.width - textSize.width)/2, y: (rect.size.height - textSize.height)/2 - 2, width: textSize.width, height: textSize.height)
        text.draw(in: textRect.integral, withAttributes: attributes as? [NSAttributedString.Key : Any])
        let resultImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return resultImage
}
```

Comment: Can you please edit this to be in swift? If this was in swift and it included the code that adjusted the image to grow to hold as many as 70 characters and shrink to hold as few as 3 characters then I would choose it.

Comment: Could you provide a link for the last paragraph?

Comment: @kelalaka :  I have done my own programming.. how can i provide link to code? Let me know if you need any other help

Comment: Can you please update your code in swift 4 or 4.2??

Comment: @BhaveshM.Sarsawa : Check now

Answer (score 5):

You can simply add a custom view as marker in Google Map.

```
let marker = GMSMarker(position: coordinate)
marker.iconView = view // Your Custom view here
```

You can use imageView (for containing that orange color box) and label (for text) above it

Comment: This seems like the most swifty way to do it.

Answer (score 5):

I tried to rewrite [Mehul Thakkar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2160144/mehul-thakkar) answer to Swift 3. Hope it will work for you. But it really easier to make custom view as [Dari](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5690400/dari) said.

```
func drawText(text:NSString, inImage:UIImage) -> UIImage? {

        let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 11)
        let size = inImage.size

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)

        inImage.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height))
        let style : NSMutableParagraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle.default.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableParagraphStyle
        style.alignment = .center
        let attributes:NSDictionary = [ NSFontAttributeName : font, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : style, NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.red ]

        let textSize = text.size(attributes: attributes as? [String : Any])
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: inImage.size.width, height: inImage.size.height)
        let textRect = CGRect(x: (rect.size.width - textSize.width)/2, y: (rect.size.height - textSize.height)/2 - 2, width: textSize.width, height: textSize.height)
        text.draw(in: textRect.integral, withAttributes: attributes as? [String : Any])
        let resultImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return resultImage
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here a Swift 5 version of [Eridana](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40488834/8738452)'s Swift conversion of  [Mehul Thakkar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40374088/8738452)'s answer.

```
func drawTextT(text:NSString, inImage:UIImage) -> UIImage? {

    let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 11)
    let size = inImage.size

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)

    inImage.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height))
    let style : NSMutableParagraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle.default.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableParagraphStyle
    style.alignment = .center
    let attributes:NSDictionary = [ NSAttributedString.Key.font : font, NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle : style, NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.red ]

    //let textSize = text.size(attributes: attributes as? [String : Any])
    let textSize = text.size(withAttributes: attributes as? [NSAttributedString.Key : Any] )

    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: inImage.size.width, height: inImage.size.height)
    let textRect = CGRect(x: (rect.size.width - textSize.width)/2, y: (rect.size.height - textSize.height)/2 - 2, width: textSize.width, height: textSize.height)
    text.draw(in: textRect.integral, withAttributes: attributes as? [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]  )

    let resultImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return resultImage
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to achieve if you have just 1 image :

```
 marker.icon = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "fault_marker")
```

1) In latest XCode write `marker.icon = "imageLiteral"`.

2) Double click the dummy image icon appeared just now.

3) select desired image.

Answer (score 0):

```
                    //func to get Image view 
                // Url String :-  Your image coming from server
//image :- Background image
                    func drawImageWithProfilePic(urlString:String, image: UIImage) -> UIImageView {

                        let imgView = UIImageView(image: image)
                        imgView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 90, height: 90)

                        let picImgView = UIImageView()
                        picImgView.sd_setImage(with:URL(string: urlString))
                        picImgView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40)
                        imgView.addSubview(picImgView)

                        picImgView.center.x = imgView.center.x
                        picImgView.center.y = imgView.center.y-10
                        picImgView.layer.cornerRadius = picImgView.frame.width/2
                        picImgView.clipsToBounds = true
                        imgView.setNeedsLayout()
                        picImgView.setNeedsLayout()

                //        let newImage = imageWithView(view: imgView)
                //        return newImage

                        return imgView
            }


    //SHOW ON MAP

         let marker = GMSMarker()
         marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: Double(lat)!, longitude:  Double(long)!)
        marker.iconView = self.drawImageWithProfilePic(urlString:getProviderImage,image: UIImage.init(named: "red")!)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple and easiest way to change icon. just replace these 3 icon (default marker.png) to your icon (1x,2x,3x).

In Google Cluster there was a problem with marker (icon) change.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pR3Rx.png]

Answer (score 0):

This is how I achieved it, completely programatically:

```
//custom markers for the map
class CustomMarker: GMSMarker {

    var label: UILabel!

    init(labelText: String, imageName: String) {
        super.init()

        let iconView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 60, height: 60)))
        iconView.image = UIImage(named: imageName)//Assign image to ImageView
        
        
        if(labelText != "1"){
            label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 25, height: 25)))
            label.frame.origin.x = 25;
            
            label.text = labelText
            label.layer.cornerRadius =  label.frame.width/2
            label.layer.masksToBounds = true
            label.backgroundColor = .white
            label.applyBorder(width: 0.5, color: .black)
            label.textAlignment = .center
            iconView.addSubview(label)
        }

        
        self.iconView = iconView
    }
}
```

Function Call:

```
let marker = CustomMarker(labelText: addressCount.description, imageName: mapItem.cMapType!.lowercased())
```

Result:

[image]