# Google Maps Marker Icon as a Circular Picture With Border

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, firebase, uiimageview

What I am trying to do is set a google map marker as ONLY a UIImage I am downloading from firebase. Currently here is my code:

```
 if let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data!) {

    let markerImageView: UIImageView? = nil

    markerImageView?.image = downloadedImage
    print(markerImageView?.image)
    markerImageView?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)

    markerImageView?.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    markerImageView?.layer.masksToBounds = false
    markerImageView?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    markerImageView?.layer.cornerRadius = (markerImageView?.frame.size.width)! / 2
    markerImageView?.clipsToBounds = true

    let actualFinalImage = markerImageView?.image

    marker.icon = actualFinalImage

}
```

I know that I am getting an image from firebase and that part is working. However, where I think the problem is with this part: `let markerImageView: UIImageView? = nil` I think setting it as nil conflicts with the marker icon and that's why this does not work. However, if I take out the nil part, I get an error saying that I can't edit markerImageView before it has been initialized.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

easier. i make an UIImage Extension that convert any image to circle.
than just put call the function.

```
extension UIImage {
    func circularImage(_ radius: CGFloat) -> UIImage? {
        var imageView = UIImageView()
        if self.size.width > self.size.height {
            imageView.frame =  CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.size.width, height: self.size.width)
            imageView.image = self
            imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        } else { imageView = UIImageView(image: self) }
        var layer: CALayer = CALayer()

        layer = imageView.layer
        layer.masksToBounds = true
        layer.cornerRadius = radius
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageView.bounds.size)
        layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let roundedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return roundedImage
    }
}
```

so when you declare gmsmarker just do it like this

```
func downloadGMSMarkerImage(url: URL,marker : GMSMarker) {
    print("Download Started")
    getDataFromUrl(url: url) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }
        print(response?.suggestedFilename ?? url.lastPathComponent)
        print("Download Finished")
        DispatchQueue.main.async() {
            let pinImage = UIImage(data: data)
            let size = CGSize(width: 44, height: 44)
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
            pinImage!.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height))
            let resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            marker.icon = resizedImage?.circularImage(22)//call function if want the image cirle

        }
    }
}
```

and
you will get result like so

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try following the guide - [Use the marker's icon property](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/marker#customize_the_marker_image)

> The following snippet creates a marker with a custom icon provided as a **`UIImage`** in the **`icon`** property. The icon is centered at London, England. The snippet assumes that your application contains an image named "house.png".

```
let position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.5, longitude: -0.127)
let london = GMSMarker(position: position)
london.title = "London"
london.icon = UIImage(named: "house")
london.map = mapView
```

For a more complete implementation of custom marker image:

```
mapView.delegate = self

let house = UIImage(named: "House")!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
let markerView = UIImageView(image: house)
markerView.tintColor = .red
londonView = markerView

let position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.5, longitude: -0.127)
let marker = GMSMarker(position: position)
marker.title = "London"
marker.iconView = markerView
marker.tracksViewChanges = true
marker.map = mapView
london = marker
```

In a related SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40211383/5995040):

```
let marker = GMSMarker()

// I have taken a pin image which is a custom image
let markerImage = UIImage(named: "mapMarker")!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)

//creating a marker view
let markerView = UIImageView(image: markerImage)

//changing the tint color of the image
markerView.tintColor = UIColor.red

marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 28.7041, longitude: 77.1025)

marker.iconView = markerView
marker.title = "New Delhi"
marker.snippet = "India"
marker.map = mapView

//comment this line if you don't wish to put a callout bubble
mapView.selectedMarker = marker
```

You'll see how he assign markerImage for the [**`UIImage`**](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimage?language=objc) to get the image, the markerview to set the image for [**`UIImageView`**](http://UIImageView). Lastly, calling the **`markerView`** as marker.iconView **`value`**.

Hope this helps.