# How to create customMarkerView using googlemap in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I want to create this customMarkerView(The view with hotel sahara star & Marine Drive) on `GoogleMap`, and should be able to see both the views on map without clicking on it.

`swift4` would be recommended.

Just like `uber`,

check the reference image.

[image]

Comment: I think you can do it if you follow the below link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40210145/google-maps-ios-sdk-custom-icons-to-be-used-as-markers[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40210145/google-maps-ios-sdk-custom-icons-to-be-used-as-markers)

Comment: @NishuPriya Thanks for your quick response, I have check the link you provided.  It does not fulfil my requirements. At a time i can show only one view.

Comment: Can you please show the code you wrote yourself to attempt a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func customMarkerView(titleText : String, markerImg : UIImage) -> UIImage{
    let mainView : UIView = UIView()
    let subView : UIView = UIView()
    let padding : CGFloat = 8.0
    let rightImgView : UIImageView = UIImageView()
    let markerImgView : UIImageView = UIImageView()
    let cfont = UIFont(name: "Roboto-Regular", size: 16.0)
    //createing marker label.
    let titleLabel : UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 4.0, y: 4.0, width: 150.0, height: cfont!.lineHeight))
    titleLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    titleLabel.font = cfont!
    titleLabel.text = titleText
    titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    titleLabel.sizeToFit()
    titleLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    let noLines = titleLabel.frame.size.height / cfont!.lineHeight

    if noLines > 2{
        titleLabel.numberOfLines = 2
        titleLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 4.0, y: 4.0, width: titleLabel.frame.width, height: 2 * cfont!.lineHeight)
    }else{
        titleLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 4.0, y: 4.0, width: titleLabel.frame.width, height: 24.0)
    }


    let rightArrow = UIImage(named: "right-arrow")
    rightImgView.frame = CGRect(x: titleLabel.frame.origin.x + titleLabel.frame.width + padding, y: 4.0, width: 24.0, height: titleLabel.frame.height)
    rightImgView.image = rightArrow!
    rightImgView.contentMode = .center

    subView.addSubview(titleLabel)
    subView.addSubview(rightImgView)

    subView.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 2 * 4.0 + titleLabel.frame.width + padding + rightImgView.frame.width, height: 2 * 4.0 + titleLabel.frame.height)
    subView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    markerImgView.frame = CGRect(x: subView.center.x - markerImg.size.width/2, y: subView.frame.height + 4.0, width: markerImg.size.width, height: markerImg.size.height)
    markerImgView.image = markerImg
    markerImgView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

    mainView.addSubview(markerImgView)

    mainView.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: subView.frame.width, height: subView.frame.height + 4.0 + markerImgView.frame.height)
    mainView.addSubview(subView)
    mainView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(mainView.bounds.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
    mainView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let icon : UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return icon
}
```

Comment: i made a custom function for the same & used it. its working flawlessly

Answer (score 0):

You can add two `MarkerViews` in map using `GMSMarker()`

Put them in an `array`
And then you can use `GMSCoordinateBounds` to focus map to show all markers.
The code below shows how to focus the map.

```
    var bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds()
    for marker in yourArrayOfMarkers
    {
        bounds = bounds.includingCoordinate(marker.position)
    }
    let update = GMSCameraUpdate.fit(bounds, withPadding: 60)
    mapView.animate(with: update)
```