# can I use Google maps and places in xcode, and can I customize the icons?

Tags: swift, xcode, google-maps, google-places-api

I want to use google maps and places on my IOS application.
Is it even possible? and if so, can I customize the icons inside google maps?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/intro

Comment: Yes you can customize the markers' images as per https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/marker#customize_the_marker_image

Comment: As for Places SDK for iOS, the documentation can be found here https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/intro

Answer (score -1):

You should read and follow this link for integration :
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start

And for custom marker follow the link :
[google maps iOS SDK: custom icons to be used as markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40210145/google-maps-ios-sdk-custom-icons-to-be-used-as-markers)

its something like this :

```
let marker = GMSMarker()

// I have taken a pin image which is a custom image

let markerImage = UIImage(named: "mapMarker")!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)

//creating a marker view

let markerView = UIImageView(image: markerImage)

//changing the tint color of the image

markerView.tintColor = UIColor.red

marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 28.7041, longitude: 77.1025)

marker.iconView = markerView
marker.title = "New Delhi"
marker.snippet = "India"
marker.map = mapView

//comment this line if you don't wish to put a callout bubble
mapView.selectedMarker = marker
```